# Are there any results giving rates of weak convergence of orthonormal sequences to zero?

Tags: functional-analysis

Motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2583649/if-bx%C3%97y%E2%86%92z-is-bounded-and-bilinear-ax-to-y-is-nuclear-and-e-n-is-an-on), I am interested in the following:

Let $\,(x_n^1)_{n \geq 1}$, $(x_n^2)_{n \geq 1}$, $(x_n^3)_{n \geq 1}$, $\,\ldots\, $ be an orthonormal sequence of square-integrable real sequences $(x_n^i)_{n \geq 1} \in l^2(\mathbb{R})$.

(By "orthonormal", I mean orthonormal with respect to the standard dot product $\langle (x_n),(y_n)\rangle = \sum_n x_ny_n$.)

It is not hard to show that for each $n \geq 1$, $x_n^i \to 0$ as $i \to \infty$.

> > Are there any results guaranteeing some order of rate of convergence of
> >     $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x_n^i|}{2^n} $$
> >     to $0$ as $i \to \infty$?

Comment: Do you want "orthonormal basis" instead of "orthonormal sequence"?

Comment: @mathworker21 No, I have no reason to necessarily require that $\mathrm{span}\{(x_n^i)_{n \geq 1} : i \geq 1\}$ is dense in $l^2(\mathbb{R})$. I was just requiring unit lengths and mutual orthogonality.

Comment: Then maybe I take issue with "it is not hard to show that...".